# Importing a text file into SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, text, import

I am trying to import a text file into MySQL but although it is importing the correct number of rows then all of the fields just show up as NULL when I open it. I have created my table and then matched the fields in the import but I still have no joy. The .txt file is seperated by tabs and I think this is where I am going wrong. I have used the following:-

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

and left it out completely but still it will not work.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Raw Data Downloads\\Files\\File1.txt" INTO TABLE Table1
IGNORE 1 LINES
( @field1, @field2, @field3 )
SET
    `field1` = @FIELD_1,
    `field2` = @FIELD_2,
    `field3` = @FIELD_3;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `@field1 != @FIELD_1`.

Comment: Thank you for tidying it up. I'm not sure what you mean by the comment though...

Comment: hes saying that after your IGNORE 1 LINES you have '@field1', '@field2'. But then in your SET, you have 'field1' = '@FIELD_1'.  Shouldnt it be '@field1'

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing to be fair. I thought that after the IGNORE 1 LINES then the fields in the parentheses are the ones that are in the table that I wish to import the data into. In the set then I think I am saying that I want 'field1' to be imported with the data from the FIELD_1 column in the text file. Is this not the case?